# Create a customized legend breaks for Highcharter map

Tags: r, legend, r-highcharter

I created a map, but I want to customize the legend breaks, not from 0 to 100, but from 60 to 100. How

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("custom/world"))

hcmap("custom/world", data = data, value = "Percent",
                          joinBy = c("iso-a3", "Code"),  name = "Map",
                          dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE, format = "{point.name}"),
                          borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                          tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2, valueSuffix = "%"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial answer how to control ticks. 
    hc_colorAxis(tickInterval = 20)